# OSX Share clipboard among different users

Tags: macos, clipboard, users

I have 1 mac with multiple users on it. Anyone knows how in OS X to copy something to your clipboard and paste it in another users his/her environment? Hoping there is some cmd+shift+alt+c shortcut for to have a multi user sharable clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: http://www.lagercrantz.name/software/clipboardsharing/

It works as an app that sits in your menu bar, when you want to copy something, click it, and click copy.

You can also use it for sharing clipboard over the local network:

[image]

Comment: Not supported on the Intel chipset :(

Comment: @Rim weird! Sorry :/